# I want to delete a specified field in the document after a particular period of time in MongoDB. How do I do it?

Tags: mongodb, ttl

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5bdff3642397ba1731d93306"),
        "fullname" : "tim",
        "email" : "tim@gmail.com",
        "password" : "$2a$10$WcSZsh/x26CfwLmFpudBcO6Rpxecpws977f/oRkZV6Vr0nmRUpOBO",
        "token" : "428pT4kvavcmmEbZGECUTeyjVEaA3NGc",
        "__v" : 0
}

    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5bdff3642397ba1731d93986"),
        "fullname" : "tim",
        "email" : "tim@gmail.com",
        "password" : "$2a$10$WcSZsh/x26CfwLmFpudBc09Rpxecpws977f/oRkZV6Vr0nmRUpOBO",
        "token" : "428pT4kvavcxdEbZGECUTeyjVEaA3NGc",
        "__v" : 0
}
```

I want to delete the "token" field only from both the documents after 5 minutes in MongoDB. Is it possible? How do I do it?

Comment: The TTL process deletes **documents** and not "fields". If you want to "update the document at a particular time" then that's up to you to write the scheduling code yourself. That's an implementation language thing, and you have not mentioned a programming language used on the question.

Comment: Using mongoose? I am creating an app and I need to set an expiry time on that token. I am using mongoose for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do it from code level alternatively you can set generatedOn/lastAccessed property in the document if the time difference between 2 times is greater than 5 min then it must be treated as expired.